# Why can't I use the onload function with an HTML Select List. I have a dynamic list that I need to update

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a web form that will list a users supply and the units of that supply in a table. The table is populated from an array "supply" that is traversed in HTML using a FOR loop as shown below.

The Units is displayed using a  HTML script, but I want to pre-select the prior unit that was selected before by the user on loading. I can't seem to use the onload function with the Select script. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>enter code here
<table id="mylist">
  <thead>
    <th>Supply</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
  </thead>
  {% for row in supply %}
    <tr >
      <td ><input type="text" name="supply" value="{{row[0]}}"></td>   

      <td ><select id="units" onload="myFunction({{row[1]}})">
          <option value="bag">bag</option>
          <option value="bottle">bottle</option>
          <option value="box">box</option>
          <option value="carton">carton</option></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>

<script>
    function myFunction1(row) {
        document.getElementById('units').value = row;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subset of DOM elements on which [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) will work. `<img>` , `<iframe>`, `<body>` are a few. `<select>` is not one of them.

If you want your select to have a default value, you will have to do something like this:

```
<select id="units">
<option value="bag"{% if row[1]=="bag" %} selected="true"{% endif %}>bag</option>
<option value="box"{% if row[1]=="box" %} selected="true"{% endif %}>box</option>
<option value="bottle"{% if row[1]=="bottle" %} selected="true"{% endif %}>bottle</option>
<option value="carton"{% if row[1]=="carton" %} selected="true"{% endif %}>carton</option>
</select>
```

If the select attribute is present in the tag, that option is selected. Remember, selected should be present in only one option. The value you give to selected attribute does not matter, it can be seleceted="false" too, even then it will be the selected attribute. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should match the `<option>` tag value with the loop value and where it will match you have to add "**selected**" attribute in `<option>` tag.
So, it should be look like this `<option value="bag" selected>bag</option>`. Just make sure only one tag should be selected.

Comment: The issue with this is because the table is being dynamically generally with a loop, each supply already created could have been created with a different Units being selected. I want the Select field to load up with the option that the material was created with, while allowing the user to be able to change the selection at any time. Tushar was able to answer this for me.